# How to enter Y when prompted using Jmeter OS process Sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am currently stuck with executing a command to transfer some file using Jmeter OS process sampler. The transfer is facilitated by a EXE file which I need to invoke and then provide the route and the file names to make that transfer happen along with a Secure Key.

I am successfully able to execute the command but this command when executed prompts the below

Press Y to continue...

I tried a number of ways to pass the input as Y but its doesn't seem to work. I have tried the below options

1. Echo Y
2. / set /y
3. /Q  to suppress the prompt
4. Created a bat file to echo y and then called it out from the OS sampler
5. Added the whole piece of command to the bat file and then echoed y

and there were few other combinations I tried but it does not seem to work.

If I provide a command in multiple lines of the OS process sampler, it simply appends to the previous command.

Any pointer would really help me out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS:- I did go through a number of links one of them was the below.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to delete file `c:\temp\test.txt`

[image]

More information:

- [How to auto answer prompts in Windows batch script](http://thirutechie.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-auto-answer-prompts-in-windows.html)
- [Redirecting Input and Output](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line/modules/learn-the-command-line-redirection/cheatsheet)
- [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Also there are 4 error messages in your script, check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries as it might be the case your JSR223 Pre-Processor is failing.

Comment: I have tried echo y| but without the inverted commas, I'll try one more time, I am not sure how the inverted comma will impact my command cause there is other piece of the command as well in double quotes. I'll try out and update the finding. Thanks

Comment: ,I tried all the below combinations does not work I tried a few more but cannot paste

"echo y|BlobFileUpload.exe OS_Sampler_New.txt" "5002a9aad6ea/fd98ac74abe-9a13-fb8ddbc9" "965-8dcb-7bff2a591" "/OS_Sampler_New.txt" "inbox" "https://ABCD.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=XYZsrt=co&sp=rwdlacitfx&se=2022-04-30T14:43:33Z&st=2022-"

Next

"echo y|BlobFileUpload.exe OS_Sampler_New.txt "5002a9aad6ea/fd98ac74abe-9a13-fb8ddbc9" "965-8dcb-7bff2a591" "/OS_Sampler_New.txt" "inbox" "https://ABCD.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=XYZsrt=co&sp=rwdlacitfx&se=2022-04-30T14:43:33Z&st=2022-""

Comment: I am not sure it will work, may be I can create a parametrized bat file cause I need to se multiple file name and in that bat file I can echo y towards the end. I 'll give this a try